# How to maximize 3 variable equations subject to a constraint?

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Let's say I want to maximise a function $f(x,y,z)=a\ln(x)+(1-a)\ln(y)-\frac{z^2}{2}$ subject to a constraint that is equal to $x+\frac{y}{1+r}=Wz$

Assume variables are all real numbers and $0<a<1$

How would I go about doing this?
z
I have tried:
$\mathcal{L}= \alpha \ln{x}+(1-\alpha)\ln{(y)}-\frac{{z}^2}{2}+ \lambda(Wz-{By}-x)$ and partially differentiating w.r.t. $x,y,z$ but I get stuck on finding $z$ as $Wz$ varies with $z$.

Attempt:
$\frac{\partial{\mathcal{L}}}{\partial{x}}=\frac{\alpha}{x}-\lambda=0$

$\frac{\alpha}{x}=\lambda$

$\frac{\partial{\mathcal{L}}}{\partial{y}}=\frac{1-\alpha}{y}-\frac{\lambda}{1+r}=0$

$\frac{1-\alpha}{y}=\frac{\lambda}{1+r}$

$\frac{(1-\alpha)(1+r)}{y}=\lambda$

$\frac{\partial{\mathcal{L}}}{\partial{z}}=W\lambda-z=0$

$W\lambda=z$

$\frac{z}{W}=\lambda$

Comment: Do you know the Lagrange multiplier technique?

Comment: @quasi just updated it with some working

Comment: @Paul I have attempted to use it, but getting stuck

Comment: @quasi no actual value for $a$, $c=\frac{1}{2}$. $W$ itself is a constant, however, $Wz$ is not constant as we are looking to choose $x,y,z$ subject to $x+By=Wz$

Comment: @thomas: Please edit your post to include an actual example with all constants specified (i.e., no unknowns other than $x,y,z$), and for that example, show an attempt.

Comment: @quasi added my attempt and where I got stuck

Answer (score 1):

Using the Lagrangian multipliers procedure:

calling

$$
f(x,y,z) = a\ln x+(1-a)\ln y -\frac 12 z^2
$$

the lagrangian can be established as

$$
L(x,y,z,\lambda) = f(x,y,z)+\lambda\left(x+\frac{y}{r+1}-z W\right)
$$

The $L$ stationary points are the solutions for

$$
\nabla L = 0 = \left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 \frac{a}{x}+\lambda  & = & 0\\
 \frac{1-a}{y}+\frac{\lambda }{r+1} & = & 0\\
 \lambda  W+z & = & 0\\
 x+\frac{y}{r+1}-W z & = & 0\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

obtaining

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 f & x & y & z & \lambda \\
a \log (a W)-(a-1) \log ((1-a) (r+1) W)-\frac{1}{2} & a W & (1-a) (r+1) W & 1 & -\frac{1}{W} \\
 a \log (-a W)-(a-1) \log ((a-1) (r+1) W)-\frac{1}{2} & -a W & (a-1) (r+1) W & -1 & \frac{1}{W} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

NOTE

Depending on the parametric values for $a,r,W$ the obtained values cannot be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Maximize

$$a\ln(x)+(1-a)\ln(y)-\frac12\left(bx+cy\right)^2$$ for $x,y$ (without constraint; auxiliary constants introduced for convenience).

> $$\dfrac ax-b(bx+cy)=\dfrac{1-a}y-c(bx+cy)=0.$$ There is no valid solution !